# Batch file with xcopy runs correctly called from cmd but not with double click

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, xcopy

I'm testing a solution for a user getting access denied when running a scheduled backup batch script or by double-clicking it.

I've noticed I have the same issue for a simple xcopy call. Specifically, if I run the xcopy string or call the batch file containing the script from cmd, it works and the file is copied, but if I double-click the file the terminal window shows up for a while and then closes, and the file is not copied. I've tried several solutions like adding a "C:" or "Cd" line, entering the full path to xcopy.exe and adding a call to cmd.exe with the /C parameter at the beginning of xcopy line. Any possible combination of these solutions brought no changes.

Edit: by adding a pause as suggested by @MicroservicesOnDDD I notice I'm getting "access denied". Now I've tried creating another bat with "runas /noprofile /user:\ ". It asks me for password and runs the other bat from which I'm still getting an access denied.
I'm using a domain user set as administrator for this computer and I'm doing all this on my default desktop. (C:\Users\\Desktop)

Comment: 1. Add a "PAUSE" command to the end of the batch file and see if there are any error messages. 2. Often the **environment** is different, which means the path (where commands are searched), the current directory (this happens **very** often). or permissions (did you create cmd.exe as Administrator before trying the batch file? and when you double-click, are you logged in as a regular user having fewer rights?) HTH

Comment: You need full paths to the files/folders not `xcopy`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just found out it was the goddamn antivirus causing the access denied issue. Sorry for bothering you.